# identify which chrome tab is using up CPU in Linux?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, cpu-usage

In my Linux laptop, I sometimes have a bunch of tabs opened in Google Chrome, which I believe creates a new process per tab. I would like to be able to pinpoint the tab that is using up the CPU. Is there an easy way to to that?

Comment: Usually it's flash plugin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well Chrome has it's own built in task manager:

Customize and Control Chrome (Wrench icon) -> Tools -> Task Manager

I have never tried it in Linux, but that is where I would start.

Since Grawity pulled his answer for completeness I'll add the keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: Or just `[Shift] + [Esc]`.